# Как отправить данные на удаленный ноутбук с сервера?

Tags: php

В общем суть заключается в следующем: на сервере лежит скрипт который будет слушать изменение в базе и отправлять эти данные на удаленный ноутбук. Каким образом лучше реализовать отправку этих данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если php скрипт будет обращаться к ноутбуку, то в данном случае ноутбук является сервером, а сервер клиентом.
Подумайте в сторону постоянного или периодического соединения от ноутбука к серверу.
Это можно сделать с помощью javascript и setInterval, либо использовать сокеты.
Если нужен дектопный клиент, то можно использовать любой подходящий для десктопа язык.